# Why convergence implies cauchy in topological vector space?

Tags: general-topology, topological-vector-spaces, cauchy-sequences

The following definition is from *Janich*'s Topology book :

> **Definition** (Topological Vector Space). A $\mathbb{R}$-Vector space $(E,\tau)$ with a topological space structure is called a *Topological Vector Space* of its topological and linear structure are compatible in the following sense :
>
> $A1.$ The subtraction ($-:E^2\rightarrow E$) is continuous.
>
> $A2.$ The multiplication by scalar $\mathbb{R}\times E\rightarrow E$ is continuous.
>
> $A3.$ $(E,\tau)$ is *Hausdorff*.

Consider definition of "convergence of a sequence to some point", given [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/289740/76758).

Again, Let the following definition from *[wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cauchy_sequence#In_topological_vector_spaces)* :

> **Definition.** $\{x_n\}$ is a *Cauchy sequence* if for each $V\in\tau$ containing $0$, there is some $N$ such that for each $m,n > N $ : 
>   $x_m-x_n\in V$.

Now I want to verify that 
$$\text{Every convergent sequence is cauchy}.$$
But it seems we don't have enough tools to prove.

Let's start ! Suppose $\{x_n\}\rightarrow x$ and let $V$ be a given open set containing $0$. By continuity of addition or subtraction, $V+x$ is a neighborhood of $x$. Therefore, 
there's a $N$ such that :
$$\forall\:m,n>N\:: 
\left\{
\begin{array}{l}x_m\in V+x\\
x_n\in V+x
\end{array}\right.\Longrightarrow
\left\{
\begin{array}{l}x_m-x\in V\\
x_n-x\in V
\end{array}\right.\tag{*}$$
But by idea of *metric spaces*, we must choose a "**smaller**" neighborhood $x$ in order to remove $x$ from the relations $(*)$.

Comment: Try to start with:if $x_n$ converges to $x$ then $\forall n>N$ $x_n \in x_N + V$. So $x_m, x_n \in x_N+V$ where $V$ is a neighborhood, now what does this tell you.

Comment: How could you say that for some $N$ :
$$\forall\;n>N \:: x_n\in x_N+V$$
?

Comment: Definition of convergence

Comment: Can you go to detail ?

Comment: Can you check this lecture notes page 183

http://www.ma.huji.ac.il/~razk/iWeb/My_Site/Teaching_files/TVS.pdf

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to consider the continuity of the map $f : E \times E \rightarrow E, (a,b) \mapsto a-b$ at the point $(x,x)$ and choose a neighbourhood $W$ of $x$ such that $f(W,W) \subset V$. Your 'smaller' neighborhood is $W$.